Kerr metric in Boyer-Lindquist-isotropic form?
The non-zero elements of the Kerr metric in advanced Eddington-Finkelstein starting from the Schwarzschild metric in isotropic coordinates is
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        g_{u\varphi} = g_{\varphi u} &= \frac{j\mu_-\left[\mu_- - \left(\mu_+\right)^3\right]\sin^2{\theta}}{\left(\mu_+\right)^2} \\
        g_{ur} = g_{ru} &= -\mu_-\mu_+ \\
        g_{r\varphi} = g_{\varphi r} &= -j\mu_-\mu_+\sin^2{\theta} \\
        g_{uu} &= \left(\frac{\mu_-}{\mu_+}\right)^2 \\
        g_{\theta\theta} &= -\left(\mu_+\right)^4\rho^2 \\
        g_{\varphi\varphi} &= \frac{j^2\left(\mu_-\right)^2\sin^4{\theta}}{\left(\mu_+\right)^2} - 2j^2\mu_+\mu_-\sin^4{\theta} - \left(\mu_+\right)^4\rho^2\sin^2{\theta}.
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Where $j=J/Mc$ is the rotation parameter, $\rho^2 = r^2 + j^2\cos^2{\theta}$ and
$$\mu_\pm = 1 \pm \frac{GMr}{2c^2\rho^2}$$
The question is, can we go from this set of coordinates directly to Boyer-Lindquist coordinates? How?

Your coordinates are not isotropic, but if you're looking for the transformation from Eddington Finkelstein style coordinates to Boyer Lindquist and back see here
